# Slowcheetah equivalent for VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, app-config, slowcheetah

I've been looking for a way to do app.config transformations. I have found [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5), but it looks like SlowCheetah does not support VS 2008. Is there any plugin equivalent of SlowCheetah for VS 2008?

Comment: Since `web.config` transformations are not supported by VS 2008, I'd be surprised to see such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XDT transforms, which SlowCheetah relies on, requires .NET 4.0. Since .NET 4.0 was after VS2008 we cannot really add support for VS2008. Also I think the extensibility model in VS2010 was a big change from VS2008.